# Pandas to process table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table loaded in Jupyter Notebook.  I am using Pandas to prepare the data before later analysis.

[image]

What I want to do is to "get a client that has highest revenue under each household.  The result should be including all columns as a table.

Can someone tell me how to use Pandas to write the codes?  Thanks.

Comment: Your question would be better if you included an example of the table directly (rather than an image), and if you showed some code for things you've already tried. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: Also refer to [MCVE] .

Comment: Sorry about that.  I have tried codes many times by my own, none of them worked.  The result wasn't what I want.  So I asked for help!